# Calling parent Mehtod From Child Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, aura, parent

I have a Parent Component inside that I have a method-

```
parentMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
            alert("inside parent");
            var payload = event.getParams().response;
           var navService = component.find("navService");
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                "recordId": payload.id,
                "objectApiName": "Opportunity",
                "actionName": "view"
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        navService.navigate(pageReference); 
        }
```

I have 3 Child Components , I want to call this method . I have Tried using Aura Method Its giving below error

```
TypeError: Action failed: c:OpportunityCustomRecordType$controller$parentMethod [payload is undefined]
```

Comment: Aura method is used for calling child component methods from parent, you are trying the reverse scenario, in this case you should use application event.

Comment: Can you provide more code of what have you achieved so far? For instance the code of you parent and child elements - it'll help us to better understand how you arranged your components.

Comment: You could not call parent method directly from child due to encapsulation and its also anti pattern. Better and recommended way would be to use component event with which you can send data from child component(s) to parent.